# Лишний отступ внизу блока, содержащего img

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
main div.image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

main div.image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="/images/nature-1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что этот код (да даже без любого CSS, просто картинка в другом теге) добавляют дополнительное пространство снизу родительского блока.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы можете заметить, что сама картинка уже "закончилась", но родительскому блоку все равно снизу добавляется некоторое свободное пространство. С чем это связано и как от этого избавиться - **вопрос**. Хотя, может быть, это нормально и добавляется вне зависимости от моего желания, прямо как margin'ы у `p`. Хотя от них можно избавиться.

Comment: Может у самой картинки внизу есть пространство, которое вы принимаете за отступ. `height: auto;` вроде не обязательно писать

Comment: @stackanon нет, у картинки нет такого. Сейчас подсвечен `div.image`, при подсветке исключительно `img` отступа нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Картинка, по умолчанию, отображается как строковый элемент, на который влияет высота строки. Именно высота строки ответственна за расстояние между `div` и `img`.

Решения два:

1. Обнулить высоту строки для обертки.
2. Сделать картинку блочным элементом.

```css
.holder {
  border: 1px solid lime;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100px;
}
.fix-1 {
  line-height: 0;
}
.fix-2 img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="fix-1">
    <img src="http://satyr.io/100x100/1" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="fix-2">
    <img src="http://satyr.io/100x100/2" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, это работает. Спасибо. Странно, что я раньше этого поведения не замечал. Похоже мой перфекционизм начинает все границы переходить XD

Comment: И да, второй вариант лучше, потому как в `.holder`  я могу потом захотеть добавить еще спан с описанием картинки, а тогда вся высота строки схлопнется, поэтому лучше сделать изображение блоковым.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> main div.image img {
>     width: 100%;
>     height: auto;
> }
> ```

Можно добавить

```
vertical-align: top;
```

либо использовать

```
display: block;
```

Comment: Плюс за `vertical-align: top`, я про него забыл

Answer (score 1):

добавте в стили к картинке display: block; - такое поведение изначально изза того что картинка по умолчанию инлаин

```
main div.image img {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: разве инлайн блок, а не просто инлайн?

Comment: @smellyshovel, вы правы, сейчас поправлю