Почему остается белый фон снизу шапки(страницы)?

По разметке туда ничего не залазит, при изменении высоты так же остается, не в чем проблема?


* {
  margin: 0;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "HeliosCond";
  src: url("../fonts/HeliosCond.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "TT Commons Pro Trial Variable";
  src: url("../fonts/TTCommonsProTrialVariable.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Plus Jakarta Sans";
  src: url("../fonts/PlusJakartaSans-Regular.woff2") format("woff2");
  font-style: normal;
}


/* OTHER PAGES */

.other-pages {
  background-color: #39282F;
}


/* NAV */

header {
  height: 833px;
  background-color: #39282F;
  position: relative;
}

nav {
  height: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.flex-container {
  min-height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.nav-menu,
.flex-box {
  width: calc(50% - 152px);
}

.flex-box {
  display: flex;
  gap: 45px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  margin-right: 53px;
}

.nav-menu {
  margin-left: 53px;
}

.icon img {
  display: block;
  width: 35px;
  height: 30px;
}

.icon {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: none;
}

button a {
  cursor: default;
}

.liked img:hover {
  content: url("../img/liked-hover.svg");
}

.nav-menu img:hover {
  content: url("../img/nav-menu-hover.svg");
  cursor: pointer;
}

.basket img:hover {
  content: url("../img/basket-hover.svg");
}

.title img:hover {
  content: url("../img/title-hover.svg");
}

.profile img:hover {
  content: url("../img/profile-hover.svg");
}


/* HEADER */

.container {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}

.white-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: (100% - 598px);
  height: calc(100% - 160px);
  right: 0;
  top: 160px;
}

.large-vector {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 820px;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}

.large-vector img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.small-vector {
  position: absolute;
  width: 568px;
  height: 679px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.cat {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 300;
  width: 889px;
  height: 475px;
}

.dog {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 606px;
  height: 621px;
}

.text-box {
  width: 595px;
  height: 296px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 259px;
  left: 64px;
}

.text-box blockquote {
  width: 350px;
  height: 17px;
  font-weight: 490;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "TT Commons Pro Trial Variable";
  line-height: 17px;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
}

.text-box h1 {
  width: 594px;
  height: 132px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 36px;
  font-family: "HeliosCond";
  line-height: 43px;
  padding-bottom: 28px;
}

.text-box p {
  width: 534px;
  height: 100px;
  font-family: "TT Commons Pro Trial Variable";
  font-weight: 490;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 20px;
  opacity: 45%;
}

.catalog-btn {
  width: 150px;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 605px;
  left: 64px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 0;
}

.catalog-btn img:hover {
  content: url("../img/catalog-btn-hover.svg");
}
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <div class="flex-container">
        <button class="nav-menu icon">
          <img src="img/navmenu.svg">
        </button>
        <div class="title">
          <img src="img/title.svg">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-box">
          <button class="liked icon">
            <a href="liked.html"><img src="img/liked.svg"></a>
          </button>
          <button class="basket icon">
            <a href="basket.html"><img src="img/basket.svg"></a>
          </button>
          <button class="profile icon">
            <a href="profile.html"><img src="img/profile.svg"></a>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="text-box">
      <blockquote>Качественное питание для вашего верного друга</blockquote>
      <h1>ПОЛНОРАЦИОННЫЙ СУХОЙ<br> И ВЛАЖНЫЙ КОРМ ДЛЯ КОШЕК<br> И СОБАК</h1>
      <p>Полнорационный корм Амири подходит для ежедневного кормления животных. В ассортименте продуктов учтены особенности разных пород и возрастных групп животных. Сбалансированное питание, высококачественные ингредиенты и комплекс витаминов и минералов
        способствуют здоровому росту и развитию животного.</p>
    </section>
    <button class="catalog-btn">
      <a href="catalog.html"><img src="img/catalog-btn.svg"></a>
    </button>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="white-circle">
        <img src="img/white-circle.png">
      </div>
      <div class="large-vector">
        <img src="img/large-vector.png">
      </div>
      <div class="small-vector">
        <img src="img/small-vector.png">
      </div>
      <div class="cat">
        <img src="img/cat.png">
      </div>
      <div class="dog">
        <img src="img/dog.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>




https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/556708/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-img

Ответы, не содержащие решения вопроса, будут удаляться. Чтобы отметить вопрос решённым, потребуется опубликовать понятное всем решение. Если же желания публиковать решение нет, вы можете просто удалить вопрос, если он неактуален.
